# GUID vs int : Does it makes any difference for SEO?

Tags: url, seo, guid

Today I heard from my colleague that search bot can index pages with sequential ids.

Is it really happens ?

As an example checkout two urls:

http://sample.com/myProduct?id=765

and

http://sample.com/myProduct?id=35d6eb6c-97f6-4cde-997c-ade657c285d3

So, if search bots can figure out that my product id in url is sequential it can possibly index other products up and down the sequence ... 
Have you ever heard anything like that ?

Comment: Perhaps the question you should be asking is: Is it user-friendly?

Comment: I know that both are not )) thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whomever told you that is mistaken. Search engines will only index pages they know exist. So they won't keep changing the ID in those URLs just see if they find anything. So if you want those other pages to be indexed you should use a HTML sitemap or [XML sitemap](http://sitemaps.org) to tell the search engines where those pages are. Linking to them from other product pages is also a good idea.